# Swift splitting UILabel between two lines

Tags: swift, uilabel

Here's a picture of a `UILabel` getting split between two lines:
[image]

I'm okay with it getting split, but it's getting split awkwardly. Is there any way to distribute the text more evenly between the two lines? I.e. to have three words (no pun intended) on each line in this case. The string is coming from user input, so I need a solution that works for any string (character limit is 40). Also, I'm doing this programatically. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a linebreak `\n` to the text where you want the split to happen.

**EDIT**

Here is a solution that splits the string in roughly half, based on spaces:

```
var str = "Hello, label, here is some variable text"

let length = str.characters.count // 40

var splitRange = str.range(of: " ", options: String.CompareOptions.literal, range: str.index(str.startIndex, offsetBy: length / 2)..<str.endIndex, locale: nil) // finds first space after halfway mark

var firstLine = str.substring(to: splitRange!.lowerBound) // "Hello, label, here is"
var secondLine = str.substring(from: splitRange!.upperBound) // "some variable text"
```

Comment: I want this to work for any string, so I don't necessarily know where I want it to break. The strings come from user input.

Comment: If you don't know how long each text will be, you would have to calculate the entire length, then programmatically insert the `/n` into the text at the halfway point.